# Why aren't OAuth2 access tokens stored as HttpOnly secure cookies? How would that work in a Node.js application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, oauth

I'm running a Node.js RESTful api where your typical response token from posting to /oauth/token would result in the following typical response

```
{
  "refresh_token": "eyJraWQiOiI2...",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "access_token": "eyJraWQiOiI2Nl...",
  "expires_in": 3600
}
```

When stored locally, aren't those tokens vulnerable to being hijacked? If they were stored as HttpOnly secure cookies how would I subsequently include them in the authorization header from the client side?

Answer (score 1):

This is how OAuth works. You receive the tokens and meta data as the body in the response. It's now up to you to store this responsibly, e.g. in a secure, HttpOnly cookie.

If the tokens were returned as cookies from the authentication server, the cookies' domain would be the *authentication* server, and would not be sent to your *application* server.

If the cookies also were HttpOnly, browser clients wouldn't be able to read the cookies, and wouldn't be able to create new cookies etc.